# Where is download location on Ubuntu web browser?

Tags: webbrowser-app

I am moving to Ubuntu web brower from Firefox and Chromium because it is faster and lighter than both. The only problem I am facing now is the location of downloaded file. I download attachment on my email, but I can't find the downloaded file. The same case for 'save image' on right click. Any one knows where is the location?

Answer (score 1):

The image files at least are stored in:

```
/home/<username>/.cache/webbrowser-app/captures
```

The problem is that the `webbrowser-app` is intended to display web apps in Unity 7 and to be used mobile-style in Unity 8. It doesn't behave like a full-featured replacement for other browsers.

Right click and image in the browser and choose: Open in new tab. You will see the saved image appear in the captures directory; but it won't look like the clean save that you would get from Firefox. Nevertheless, that is the saved image file.

Downloads are handled (in a way that I haven't fully figured out) in

```
/home/<username>/.local/share/webbrowser-app
```

through the `LocalStorage` directory and sqlite databases.

I think you may find that the current `webbrowser-app` may not be fully suitable as a replacement for standard browsers. There are other light browsers. The most full-featured is (imo) `midori`.

Comment: Great! but I only see the png files of the browser (screenshots), no pdf files that I already downloaded, nor the image file that I want to save (right click on image >> save image)